# Amplitude Modulation Equation (sine or cosine)

Tags: telecommunications, amplitude-modulation

I got an exam tomorrow and I'm still confused with something. I'm sure most people are familiar with the general equation of Amplitude Modulation.

AM(t) = (Ac+m(t))cos ωc t

I found that there is another variant of which cosine is changed with sine.

AM(t) = (Ac+m(t))sin ωc t

And this also applied to both c(t) and m(t) somehow. My thought is that both can be used and it just depends on the waveform/equation given in questions. In my class we used only the one with cosine, so I never get the explanation for this.

Comment: Funnily enough, if you move the receiver 1/4 wavelength further away from the transmitter, that cosine becomes a sine...

Comment: Welcome Syahrul, please see [this link](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/test-the-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question) for how to use MathJax to beautify mathematics on this site.  If you click [Edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/571613/edit) below your question, you can make those formulas look pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, both can be used. The useful information you want to transmit through amplitude modulation is contained within the (Ac+m(t)) expression. So the fact that you use a sine or a cosine doesn't really matter in the end.